# Is there a DRYer way to create this jquery quote generator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

This is one of my first real apps I've made with javascript(jQuery) so I know my approach probably isn't the best and my lengthy code shows. I created this simple app that spits out what customers can expect to pay if they purchase our software, but it has a TON of price points and with my limited knowledge this was the only way I could think of to do it.

http://codepen.io/ajrdesign/pen/BdHrl

JS:

```
/* I'm a HUGE js noob so if there is a better DRY way to do this PLEASE let me know. */

$(document).ready(function() {

/* COST ARRAYS */
 var standardCost = [179, 159, 139, 129, 119, 109, 99, 89, 79, 69];
 var standardMaintenance = [228, 198, 168, 156, 144, 132, 120, 108, 96, 84];
 var standardSavings = [0, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110];
 var standardMaintenanceSavings = [0, 30, 60, 72, 84, 96, 108, 120, 132, 144];
 var cadCost = [239, 199, 179, 159, 149, 129, 119, 109, 99, 89];
 var cadMaintenance = [298, 248, 212, 190, 178, 156, 144, 132, 120, 108];
 var cadSavings = [0, 30, 60, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140];
 var cadMaintenanceSavings = [0, 50, 86, 108, 120, 142, 154, 166, 178, 190];
 var extremeCost = [299, 249, 219, 199, 179, 159, 149, 129, 119, 109];
 var extremeMaintenance = [368, 308, 268, 238, 214, 192, 180, 156, 144, 132];
 var extremeSavings = [0, 50, 80, 100, 120, 140, 150, 170, 180, 190];
 var extremeMaintenanceSavings = [0, 60, 100, 130, 154, 166, 188, 212, 224, 236];


  var calculateCosts = function() {

    var value = $("#seats").val();
    var cost = standardCost[0];
    var savings = 0;
    var edition = $("#edition").val();
    /* STANDARD VALUES */
        if(value > 4 && edition === "standard") {
          var cost = standardCost[1];
          var savings = standardSavings[1];
        }
        if(value > 9 && edition === "standard") {
          var cost = standardCost[2];
          var savings = standardSavings[2];
        }
        if(value > 24 && edition === "standard") {
          var cost = standardCost[3];
          var savings = standardSavings[3];
        }
        if(value > 49 && edition === "standard") {
          var cost = standardCost[4];
          var savings = standardSavings[4];
        }
        if(value > 99 && edition === "standard") {
          var cost = standardCost[5];
          var savings = standardSavings[5];
        }
        if(value > 199 && edition === "standard") {
          var cost = standardCost[6];
          var savings = standardSavings[6];
        }
        if(value > 349 && edition === "standard") {
          var cost = standardCost[7];
          var savings = standardSavings[7];
        }
        if(value > 499 && edition === "standard") {
          var cost = standardCost[8];
          var savings = standardSavings[8];
        }
        if(value > 999 && edition === "standard") {
          var cost = standardCost[9];
          var savings = standardSavings[9];
        }

       /* ==== Standard with maintenance =====*/
        if(edition === "standard" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = standardMaintenance[0];
          var savings = standardMaintenanceSavings[0];
        }

       if(value > 4 && edition === "standard" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = standardMaintenance[1];
          var savings = standardMaintenanceSavings[1];
        }
        if(value > 9 && edition === "standard" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = standardMaintenance[2];
          var savings = standardMaintenanceSavings[2];
        }
        if(value > 24 && edition === "standard" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = standardMaintenance[3];
          var savings = standardMaintenanceSavings[3];
        }
        if(value > 49 && edition === "standard" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = standardMaintenance[4];
          var savings = standardMaintenanceSavings[4];
        }
        if(value > 99 && edition === "standard" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = standardMaintenance[5];
          var savings = standardMaintenanceSavings[5];
        }
        if(value > 199 && edition === "standard" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = standardMaintenance[6];
          var savings = standardMaintenanceSavings[6];
        }
        if(value > 349 && edition === "standard" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = standardMaintenance[7];
          var savings = standardMaintenanceSavings[7];
        }
        if(value > 499 && edition === "standard" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = standardMaintenance[8];
          var savings = standardMaintenanceSavings[8];
        }
        if(value > 999 && edition === "standard" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = standardMaintenance[9];
          var savings = standardMaintenanceSavings[9];
        }

        /* CAD VALUES */
        if(edition === "cad") {
          var cost = cadCost[0];
          var savings = cadSavings[0];
        }
        if(value > 4 && edition === "cad") {
          var cost = cadCost[1];
          var savings = cadSavings[1];
        }
        if(value > 9 && edition === "cad") {
          var cost = cadCost[2];
          var savings = cadSavings[2];
        }
        if(value > 24 && edition === "cad") {
          var cost = cadCost[3];
          var savings = cadSavings[3];
        }
        if(value > 49 && edition === "cad") {
          var cost = cadCost[4];
          var savings = cadSavings[4];
        }
        if(value > 99 && edition === "cad") {
          var cost = cadCost[5];
          var savings = cadSavings[5];
        }
        if(value > 199 && edition === "cad") {
          var cost = cadCost[6];
          var savings = cadSavings[6];
        }
        if(value > 349 && edition === "cad") {
          var cost = cadCost[7];
          var savings = cadSavings[7];
        }
        if(value > 499 && edition === "cad") {
          var cost = cadCost[8];
          var savings = cadSavings[8];
        }
        if(value > 999 && edition === "cad") {
          var cost = cadCost[9];
          var savings = cadSavings[9];
        }

       /* ==== CAD with maintenance =====*/
        if(edition === "cad" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = cadMaintenance[0];
          var savings = cadMaintenanceSavings[0];
        }

       if(value > 4 && edition === "cad" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = cadMaintenance[1];
          var savings = cadMaintenanceSavings[1];
        }
        if(value > 9 && edition === "cad" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = cadMaintenance[2];
          var savings = cadMaintenanceSavings[2];
        }
        if(value > 24 && edition === "cad" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = cadMaintenance[3];
          var savings = cadMaintenanceSavings[3];
        }
        if(value > 49 && edition === "cad" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = cadMaintenance[4];
          var savings = cadMaintenanceSavings[4];
        }
        if(value > 99 && edition === "cad" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = cadMaintenance[5];
          var savings = cadMaintenanceSavings[5];
        }
        if(value > 199 && edition === "cad" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = cadMaintenance[6];
          var savings = cadMaintenanceSavings[6];
        }
        if(value > 349 && edition === "cad" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = cadMaintenance[7];
          var savings = cadMaintenanceSavings[7];
        }
        if(value > 499 && edition === "cad" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = cadMaintenance[8];
          var savings = cadMaintenanceSavings[8];
        }
        if(value > 999 && edition === "cad" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = cadMaintenance[9];
          var savings = cadMaintenanceSavings[9];
        } 

        /* EXTRME VALUES */
        if(edition === "extreme") {
          var cost = extremeCost[0];
          var savings = extremeSavings[0];
        }
        if(value > 4 && edition === "extreme") {
          var cost = extremeCost[1];
          var savings = extremeSavings[1];
        }
        if(value > 9 && edition === "extreme") {
          var cost = extremeCost[2];
          var savings = extremeSavings[2];
        }
        if(value > 24 && edition === "extreme") {
          var cost = extremeCost[3];
          var savings = extremeSavings[3];
        }
        if(value > 49 && edition === "extreme") {
          var cost = extremeCost[4];
          var savings = extremeSavings[4];
        }
        if(value > 99 && edition === "extreme") {
          var cost = extremeCost[5];
          var savings = extremeSavings[5];
        }
        if(value > 199 && edition === "extreme") {
          var cost = extremeCost[6];
          var savings = extremeSavings[6];
        }
        if(value > 349 && edition === "extreme") {
          var cost = extremeCost[7];
          var savings = extremeSavings[7];
        }
        if(value > 499 && edition === "extreme") {
          var cost = extremeCost[8];
          var savings = extremeSavings[8];
        }
        if(value > 999 && edition === "extreme") {
          var cost = extremeCost[9];
          var savings = extremeSavings[9];
        }

       /* ==== EXTREME with maintenance =====*/
        if(edition === "extreme" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = extremeMaintenance[0];
          var savings = extremeMaintenanceSavings[0];
        }

       if(value > 4 && edition === "extreme" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = extremeMaintenance[1];
          var savings = extremeMaintenanceSavings[1];
        }
        if(value > 9 && edition === "extreme" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = extremeMaintenance[2];
          var savings = extremeMaintenanceSavings[2];
        }
        if(value > 24 && edition === "extreme" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = extremeMaintenance[3];
          var savings = extremeMaintenanceSavings[3];
        }
        if(value > 49 && edition === "extreme" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = extremeMaintenance[4];
          var savings = extremeMaintenanceSavings[4];
        }
        if(value > 99 && edition === "extreme" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = extremeMaintenance[5];
          var savings = extremeMaintenanceSavings[5];
        }
        if(value > 199 && edition === "extreme" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = extremeMaintenance[6];
          var savings = extremeMaintenanceSavings[6];
        }
        if(value > 349 && edition === "extreme" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = extremeMaintenance[7];
          var savings = extremeMaintenanceSavings[7];
        }
        if(value > 499 && edition === "extreme" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = extremeMaintenance[8];
          var savings = extremeMaintenanceSavings[8];
        }
        if(value > 999 && edition === "extreme" && $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked')) {
          var cost = extremeMaintenance[9];
          var savings = extremeMaintenanceSavings[9];
        }    

    $("#totalCost").text("$" + value * cost);
    $("#perSeat").text("$" + cost);
    $("#savings").text("$" + value*savings);
   };

/*
Triggers so it caluclates on both input and select/checkmark
*/
  $("#priceForm").keyup(calculateCosts);
  $("#priceForm").change(calculateCosts);
});
```

HTML:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<h4>I'm looking to buy:</h4>
<div id="priceForm">
      <input id="seats" maxlength="6" id="numberOfSeats" type="text" value="1"/>
    <p>seats of</p>
    <select id="edition" name="carlist" form="carform">
      <option value="standard">Standard</option>
      <option value="cad">CAD</option>
      <option value="extreme">eXtreme</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label  for="maintenance">Maintenance</label>
    <input id="checkMaintenance" type="checkbox" name="maintenance" value="maintenance">
</div>

<hr />

<div class="costs-container">
  <h4>Cost Per Seat:</h4>
  <p id="perSeat"></p>
</div>
<div class="costs-container">
  <h4>My Total Cost:</h4>
  <p id="totalCost"></p>
</div>
<div class="costs-container">
  <h4>My Savings:</h4>
<p id="savings"></p>
</div>
```

Everything functions fine but I just feel like there's gotta be a better way to do this type of thing. Can anyone point me in the right direction? What am I not thinking about?

Comment: I'll gladly retract my downvote (and perhaps even turn it into an upvote) if/when this post gets edited with actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: reorganize your variables, nested in a manner resembling the tests you need to do.

```
var prices = {
  standard: {
    cost:    { normal:      [ 179 , 159 , 139 , 129 , 119 , 109 , 99  , 89  , 79  , 69  ],
               maintenance: [ 228 , 198 , 168 , 156 , 144 , 132 , 120 , 108 , 96  , 84  ] },
    savings: { normal:      [ 0   , 20  , 40  , 50  , 60  , 70  , 80  , 90  , 100 , 110 ],
               maintenance: [ 0   , 30  , 60  , 72  , 84  , 96  , 108 , 120 , 132 , 144 ] }
  }, cad: {
    cost:    { normal:      [ 239 , 199 , 179 , 159 , 149 , 129 , 119 , 109 , 99  , 89  ],
               maintenance: [ 298 , 248 , 212 , 190 , 178 , 156 , 144 , 132 , 120 , 108 ] },
    savings: { normal:      [ 0   , 30  , 60  , 80  , 90  , 100 , 110 , 120 , 130 , 140 ],
               maintenance: [ 0   , 50  , 86  , 108 , 120 , 142 , 154 , 166 , 178 , 190 ] }
  }, extreme: {
    cost:    { normal:      [ 299 , 249 , 219 , 199 , 179 , 159 , 149 , 129 , 119 , 109 ],
               maintenance: [ 368 , 308 , 268 , 238 , 214 , 192 , 180 , 156 , 144 , 132 ] },
    savings: { normal:      [ 0   , 50  , 80  , 100 , 120 , 140 , 150 , 170 , 180 , 190 ],
               maintenance: [ 0   , 60  , 100 , 130 , 154 , 166 , 188 , 212 , 224 , 236 ] }
  }
};
```

Step 2: consolidate your threshold tests

```
var thresholds = [ 4, 9, 24, 99, 199, 349, 499, 999 ];
// this function could be optimized, using a binary search rather than linear.
// However, it's fixed length, so you don't really need to worry.
var getIndexForThreshold = function(value) {
  var l = thresholds.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (value <= thresholds[i]) { return i; }
  }
  return l;
};
```

Step 3: put it all together

```
var calculateCosts = function() {

  var value = $("#seats").val();
  var edition = $("#edition").val();
  var maintenance = $('#checkMaintenance').is(':checked') ? 'maintenance' : 'normal';

  // These 3 lines here replace the 20-30 if statements in the original implementation
  var thresholdIndex = getIndexForThreshold(value);
  var cost = prices[edition].cost[maintenance][thresholdIndex];
  var savings = prices[edition].savings[maintenance][thresholdIndex];

  $("#totalCost").text("$" + value * cost);
  $("#perSeat").text("$" + cost);
  $("#savings").text("$" + value*savings);
 };

  /*
  Triggers so it caluclates on both input and select/checkmark
  */
  $("#priceForm").on('keyup change', calculateCosts);
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dvcwe

A few final comments: don't declare the same variable name more than once. Use JSHint. Read "Javascript: The good parts". Cache your jquery objects. Avoid using IDs, unless you can ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks I'll be sifting through this to see if I can make sense of it all.

Comment: Sorry, [we hate fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).